# Serverless Configuration warning at 'functions.app.events[0]': unsupported function event

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy an AWS API with serverless.com

When I do:

```
sls --stage=dev --aws-profile=myprofile deploy --force
```

I get the following warning:

```
Configuration warning at 'functions.app.events[0]': unsupported function event
```

My serverless.yml contains the section:

```yaml
functions:
  app:
    handler: src/index.handler
    memorySize: 3008
    events:
      - httpApi:
        method: '*'
        path: '*'
        authorizer:
          name: serviceAuthorizer
          scopes: # Optional
            - user.id
            - user.email
```

What is wrong with the events section?

Comment: Why is the path a '*'? Did you mean '/'?

Comment: I want all paths to be handled by this function. Anyway if i use path: '/' I still get the warning

Comment: Since you're trying to catch all methods and any path, try this `events: - httpApi: '*'` as decribed here - https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api/#catch-alls

Comment: Removed method and path and added wildcard. With that I get:  Configuration warning at 'functions.app.events[0]': unrecognized property 'authorizer'

Comment: Authorizer config is probably not supported for catch all and any scenarios? I'm not sure though, it doesn't say that anywhere in the docs.

Comment: In that case if I specified:         method: 'GET'
        path: '/'
then I shouldn't get:  unsupported function event.  - but I do

Comment: Right, not sure what could be causing it. Try `events: - httpApi: '*'` but do not include the `authorizer` just to see if it still complains

Comment: Found the schema for the function event in the source files - https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/b867df147aea5e1f57a9d275e2a389efbbcf38aa/lib/plugins/aws/package/compile/events/httpApi/index.js#L55-L85 and from looking at it, your YAML definition looks good except may be the indentation. Try fixing the indentations, never know if that's the issue. Also, btw, do you have the authorizer provider set up like here - https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api#1-configure-authorizers-on-providerhttpapiauthorizers?

Comment: Doesn't create the error when I remove the authorizer section in events.
I do have an authorizer on the API as per the link.
I'm wondering if this is a false error. Will see if I can deploy anyway

Comment: I'd recommend using a linter extension like the one for VSCode (kddejong.vscode-cfn-lint - I don't know your IDE) to parse your template and show problems with it.

Answer (score 69):

The issue is indeed indentation. The indentation on this is weird so I will explain it below. Every `·` is a space:

```
functions:
··hello:
····handler: handler.hello
····events:
······- http:
··········path: /hello
··········method: get
```

Some pointers:

- There is a space after the `- http:` hyphen.
- The next line is indented oddly - this is what's causing the issue. Rather than just two spaces of indent after defining our event type (http in my case), there are actually 4. I don't know why but that's what it demands.

---

**Another tip:** if you find your text editor is auto-formatting your YAML file and replacing the space indentation with tabs or whatever, add a `.editorconfig` file to the root with these settings:

```
[*.yml]
indent_size = 2
indent_style = spaces
```

Comment: You saved my day... and now let somebody tell me that hunting for missing `;` is bigger problem than hunting for missing two spaces... I almost pulled half of my hair today.

Comment: dude. You just made my day. It just requires 4 spaces below - http: THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: My hero, seriously.

Answer (score 34):

I had a similar issue. The problem was with indentation. Try to fix it like this:

```yaml
- httpApi:
    method: '*'
    path: '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the similer issue,
I solve by remove the prefix sapace from http

events:
- http:
path: /PostFunction
method: POST

this is the correct one
events:

- http:
  path: /PostFunction
  method: POST